# Linux whole-line sort does not sort correctly

Tags: linux, sort, posix

I want to whole-line sort a file with the linux command `sort`.

My file `cat hello`

```
#_
*
#1
```

When run with `sort hello`

```
#_
*
#1
```

Because `#` stands before `*` in asccii table, my expected result is

```
#_
#1
*
```

Is there anyone can explain me why? Thank you.

---

Update

My `locale` result is

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

---

Update 2

`sort --debug hello` result

```
sort --debug hello
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
#_
__
*
_
#1
__
```

---

Update 3

My OS version detail

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan

# sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

When I ran in another PC, the result is different

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

# sort --version    
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.

# sort hello    
*
#_
#1
```

Comment: What locale are you using? (`locale` will tell you, as will `sort --debug`.) `sort` uses the locale’s sort order and collation rules, not the ASCII order.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have updated my question

Comment: Looks correct to me for `en_US`.  If you want to sort by character value with no collation, then you should set `LANG=C` for your process.

Comment: In spanish is *
#_
#1

Comment: thank you. I think I got my answer by `LC_ALL=C sort hello`